# Добавить слово в строку

Tags: php

Как в нужную строку добавить слово.
Есть текст в text.txt

```
аааа;1213;ппп;ууу;иии;яяя;
ааааа;12432;ммм;ууум;иииа;яяяу;
```

как добавить слово 'Name'(после 'яяяу;' ) в строку где есть '12432'

Comment: Проверяй строку на наличие '12432' (strpos), если есть, заменяй 'яяяу;' на 'яяяу;Name'

Comment: @Akina и как сделать $fo1 = fopen("text.txt", "r"); $fd1 = fread($fo1, filesize("text.txt")); fclose($fo1);  в  текстовом файле дозапись?

Comment: *в текстовом файле дозапись?* ДО-запись - это append, добавление в конец. А вот добавление в середину с "раздвиганием" - не существует. Перезаписывай файл полностью новым содержимым вместо старого.

Comment: Сделал но кастыль, отодвигаю строку с такимиже данными .. https://pastebin.com/pDhHDgbT

Comment: То есть на чтение открыть и прочитать Вы можете, а открыть на запись и записать - нет? нипанимаю...

Comment: @Akina  pastebin.com/pDhHDgbT  сама попробуй создать файлик и поэкспериментировать, я добился менять строку со второго разделения ; и дозаписывать в конец строки недостающие значения + то слово